# Symfony 6.2: Querying database in a General Availability Test

Tags: testing, phpunit, symfony6

I ran into a strange problem coding a general availability test for my website. The class looks like this:

```
class GeneralAvailabilityTest extends WebTestCase
{

    /**
     * @dataProvider urlProvider
     */
    public function testGeneralAvailability($url): void
    {
        $client = static::createClient();
        $client->request('GET', $url);

        $this->assertResponseIsSuccessful();
    }

    public function urlProvider()
    {
        /*
         * Pages
         */
        yield['/'];
        yield['/blog'];
[...]
    }
}
```

This works great. Now I have a couple of blog posts which are in a BlogPostRepository using Doctrine. Instead of writing a yield[$url] in the data provider I tried to write a test function that reads the Repository, creates an url for every blog post, and finally checks for a 200 response:

```
    /**
     * Test blog posts
     */
    public function testBlogPostsGeneralAvailability(): void
    {
        $client = static::createClient();
        $BlogRepository = static::getContainer()->get(BlogPostRepository::class);
        $BlogPosts = $BlogRepository->findAll();
        foreach($BlogPosts as $BlogPost) {
            $url = "/blog/" . $BlogPost->getPostDate() . "/" . $BlogPost->getSlug();
            $client->request('GET', $url);
            $this->assertResponseIsSuccessful('ERROR GET ' . $url);
        }
    }
```

This also works fine. But: the testBlogPostsGeneralAvailability() is considered to be one test by PHPUnit, no matter how many blog posts are tested, there is only one dot "."

So I decided to move this code to the data provider instead:

```
        $BlogRepository = static::getContainer()->get(BlogPostRepository::class);
        $BlogPosts = $BlogRepository->findAll();
        foreach($BlogPosts as $BlogPost) {
            $url = "/blog/" . $BlogPost->getPostDate() . "/" . $BlogPost->getSlug();
            yield[$url];
        }
```

Now the first test fails mentioning that there is a "LogicException: Booting the kernel before calling "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase::createClient()" is not supported, the kernel should only be booted once." Starting from the second test, everything is fine.

The static::getContainer() is likely booting the kernel? Guess I have to clean up after accessing the database and before leaving the data provider function. Any ideas what and how to clean up there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by querying the database with mysqli, without instantiating Doctrine:

```
<?php
# /src/Service/BlogPostEnumerator.php
namespace App\Service;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Tools\DsnParser;

class BlogPostEnumerator
{

    /**
     * Generates a list of blog post URLs for testing purpose
     *
     * @return array of string
     */
    public function getBlogPostUrlList() : array
    {
        $BlogPostUrlList = [];
        $DbConnectString = $_ENV['DATABASE_URL'];
        $DsnParser = new DsnParser();
        $ConnectionParams = $DsnParser->parse($DbConnectString);
        $MysqlHandle = mysqli_connect($ConnectionParams["host"], $ConnectionParams["user"], $ConnectionParams["password"], $ConnectionParams["dbname"]);
        $MysqlQuery = mysqli_query($MysqlHandle, "SELECT post_date, title FROM  blog_post");
        $BlogPosts = mysqli_fetch_all($MysqlQuery, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        foreach($BlogPosts as $BlogPost) {
            $url = "/blog/" . $BlogPost["post_date"] . "/" . $this->slugify($BlogPost["title"]);
            $BlogPostUrlList[] = $url;
        }
        mysqli_free_result($MysqlQuery);
        mysqli_close($MysqlHandle);
        return $BlogPostUrlList;
    }
[...]
  public function slugify($url): string {...}
}
```

I know that my test server uses Mysql/Mariadb and the mysqli module is installed and loaded. The code is only executed in a test environment. So I'm *almost* sure it won't cause any problems on production.

And even if you don't use Mysql on production, the mysqli module is very likely installed. YAY! :)